# Game Board Algorithm

Tags: c#

I get a dictionary of a bunch of game pieces with the three properties:

Address = Location in a game piece 
Offset = Offset from the left of where the game piece is connected
Width = Width of the game piece (One, Two or Three wide)

The gameboard itself is 6 wide and 5 high (A total of 30 possible positions)

25 26 27 28 29 30
19 20 21 22 23 24
13 14 15 16 17 18
07 08 09 10 11 12
01 02 03 04 05 06

Each number is the corresponding address on the board.

I would like to be able to add all these pieces to a collection like           `ObservableCollection<GameRow> GameRows` where

```
public class GameRow
{
    public ObservableCollection<GamePiece> Row { get; set; }

    public GameRow(ArrayList<GamePiece> gamePieces)
    {
        Row = new ObservableCollection<GamePiece>();

        foreach (GamePiece gamePiece in gamePieces)
        {
            Row.Add(gamePiece);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class GamePiece
{
    public string Width { get; set; }  
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int Address {get; set}
}
```

I also need to create a gamepiece for any unused area on the board that is a single width and a color gray (the other game pieces should have a color of yellow).

Here is what the game pieces look like:

One wide: 
X  (offset = 0)

Two Wide: 
0X (offset = 1)

Three Wide 
0X0 (offset = 1)

X = What is reported as the address for that piece
0 = The empty space it occupies.

I'm trying to come up with a way to parse that dictionary of game pieces I receive into GameRows.

Example:

Lets say I get three pieces. {Address=2, Width = 1, Offset = 0},{Address=12, Width = 2, Offset = 1}, {Address=23, Width = 3, Offset = 1}

I know the address 2 piece will be on the first row and take position 02 and the rest of the game pieces for that board should be blank gamepieces with a width of 1.  The piece that is address 12 will be in the second row and take positions 11 and 12.  The piece that is address 23 will be in the 4th row and take positions 22, 23, 24.  The ObservableCollection GameRows will have five GameRow objects in it.  The GameRow object for row 4 will contain 4 objects in the Row collection.  The first 3 being blank pieces will be {Width = 1, Color = Gray} and the last piece will be a {Width = 3, Color = Yellow}

Comment: What do you mean by parse into game rows.  Such as: 01 02 03 04 05 06 = Row1, 07 08 09 10 11 12 = Row2 ?  If so I can help with this.  If not I need to understand what you want.

Comment: I added an example in the question

Comment: "I'm trying to come up with a way to parse that dictionary of game pieces I receive into GameRows."
Are you receiving a Dictionary because in your code it's an ArrayList? I was going to ask where Address is being stored and why it isn't a property of GamePiece. But assuming gamePieces is a Dictionary, does the Key mean Address? And what is the purpose of Offset? Unless gamepiece configurations like "X0" and "00X" are valid, it seems redundant.

Comment: I have no control over what I receive, it's just a dictionary with a key that is a guid and a datatype that contains an offset, address, and width.  GamePiece should have a property address, I updated my answer.  The purpose of offset is to let you know all the address positions it covers.

Comment: I think you're still leaving out some crucial info here that Sorax was trying to get at.  Can a piece that has width=3 ever have an offset of 0 or 2?  ex) Is it possible to have a piece represented as {Address=01, Width=3, Offset=0} or should we instead assume that this would be defined as {Address=02, Width=3, Offset=1}?

Comment: I assume GamePiece.Width is an int. Or is is a string representation of the int value? Or is it the strings "X", "OX", "OXO"?

Comment: A piece with a width of 3 or 2 will always have an offset of 1.

Comment: The width will be an integer value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically create a board with the empty, or Gray, pieces. Process the dictionary, removing the gray pieces that are no longer needed and adding the yellow pieces. Then process the board row by row to return an array of rows. Unit tests are included for your test cases. Modify ROWS and COLS to accomodate any size board.

```
    public class UnitTest1
{
    int ROWS = 5;
    int COLS = 6;

    public class GamePiece
    {
        public int Width;
        public string Color;
        public int Address;
        public int Offset;

    }
    public class GameRow
    {
        public List<GamePiece> Row = new List<GamePiece>();

    }

    private void initializeBoard(GamePiece[] board) {
        for(int i = 1; i < board.Length; i++) board[i] = EmptyPiece(i);
    }

    private GamePiece EmptyPiece(int address)
    {
        return new GamePiece
        {
            Address = address,
            Width = 1,
            Color = "Gray",
            Offset = 0
        };
    }

    private int ComputeRow(int address)
    {
        return ((address - 1) / COLS);
    }

    private void processDictionary(GamePiece[] board, Dictionary<int,GamePiece> d)
    {
        foreach (var piece in d.Values)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < piece.Width; i++)
            {
                board[piece.Address - piece.Offset + i] = null;
            }
            board[piece.Address] = piece;
        }
    }

    private GameRow[] convertBoardtoRows(GamePiece[] board)
    {
        var rows = new GameRow[ROWS];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++) rows[i] = new GameRow();
        for (int i = 1; i < board.Length; i++)
        {
            if (board[i] != null)
            {
                rows[ComputeRow(i)].Row.Add(board[i]);
            }
        }
        return rows;
    }

    public GameRow[] ProcessPieces(Dictionary<int, GamePiece> dictionary)
    {
        GamePiece[] board = new GamePiece[ROWS*COLS+1];
        initializeBoard(board);
        processDictionary(board, dictionary);
        return convertBoardtoRows(board);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, GamePiece>();
        dictionary.Add(1, new GamePiece { Address = 2, Width = 1, Offset = 0, Color = "Yellow" });
        dictionary.Add(2, new GamePiece { Address = 12, Width = 2, Offset = 1, Color = "Yellow" });
        dictionary.Add(3, new GamePiece { Address = 23, Width = 3, Offset = 1, Color = "Yellow" });

        var rows = ProcessPieces(dictionary);

        Assert.IsTrue(rows[0].Row.Count == 6);
        Assert.IsTrue(rows[0].Row.Where(p => p.Color == "Yellow").Count() == 1);
        Assert.IsTrue(rows[0].Row.Where(p => p.Color == "Gray").Count() == 5);
        var piece = rows[0].Row.Where(p => p.Color == "Yellow").First();
        Assert.IsTrue(piece.Address == 2);

        Assert.IsTrue(rows[1].Row.Count == 5);
        Assert.IsTrue(rows[1].Row.Where(p => p.Color == "Yellow").Count() == 1);
        Assert.IsTrue(rows[1].Row.Where(p => p.Color == "Gray").Count() == 4);
        Assert.IsTrue(rows[1].Row.Where(p => p.Address == 11).Count() == 0);
        piece = rows[1].Row.Where(p => p.Color == "Yellow").First();
        Assert.IsTrue(piece.Address == 12);

        Assert.IsTrue(rows[2].Row.Count == 6);
        Assert.IsTrue(rows[2].Row.Where(p => p.Color == "Yellow").Count() == 0);
        Assert.IsTrue(rows[2].Row.Where(p => p.Color == "Gray").Count() == 6);

        Assert.IsTrue(rows[3].Row.Count == 4);
        Assert.IsTrue(rows[3].Row.Where(p => p.Color == "Yellow").Count() == 1);
        Assert.IsTrue(rows[3].Row.Where(p => p.Color == "Gray").Count() == 3);

        Assert.IsTrue(rows[4].Row.Count == 6);
        Assert.IsTrue(rows[4].Row.Where(p => p.Color == "Yellow").Count() == 0);
        Assert.IsTrue(rows[4].Row.Where(p => p.Color == "Gray").Count() == 6);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the effort and because this is sort of how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm including `Offset` to the `GamePiece` class for the sake of brevity.

```
public class GamePiece
{
    public string Width { get; set; }  
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int Address {get; set}
    public int Offset {get; set }
}
```

I'm also leaving out the details of function `CreateOccupiedPiece` referenced below:

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, string>();

int rowWidth;
int curCol;
int address;
string value;
GamePiece curPiece;

for (int rowNum=1; rowNum<=6; rowNum++)
{
   rowWidth = 0;
   curCol = 1;
   while (rowWidth < 6) && (curCol <=6)
   {
      address = 6*(RowNum-1) + (curCol)

      if (d.TryGetValue(address, out value))
      {
         // CreateOccupiedPiece returns New Populated GamePiece
         curPiece = CreateOccupiedPiece(value);

         // Offset value will be tell us how many previous GamePieces to delete
         // as well as how much to adjust our rowWidth             
         if (curPiece.Offset > 0)
         {
            list.RemoveRange((curCol - curPiece.Offset - 1), curPiece.Offset);
            rowWidth = rowWidth - curPiece.Offset;
         }            
      }
      else
      {
         // Just add an empty space (gray, 1-width piece, at location)
         curPiece = new GamePiece("Gray", "1", address); 
      } 
      Row.Add(curPiece);
      curCol++;
      rowWidth = rowWidth + Convert.ToInt32(curPiece.Width);
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think column is the key into the dictionary.

Comment: Nice catch! I updated my answer using address instead of curCol for the key.

Comment: It's not clear if address is the key either. My solution ignores the key.